# How to specify which fields to keep while deleting the remainder of the attribute table - ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, delete

I have an attribute table with 100+ fields whereby I only need to keep 3 fields. Specifying which fields to keep is way easier than manually selecting which to delete. This should be easily done via the function [arcpy.DeleteField_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete-field.htm). However when I try to use "KEEP_FIELDS" as one of the arguments in arcpy.DeleteField_management, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: DeleteField() takes from 0 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What can be a cause for and/or solution to this error?

Code:
`arcpy.DeleteField_management(input_data, ["AFSTAND", "Shape"], "KEEP_FIELDS")`

Comment: Instead of deleting so many fields, why not just create the new feature class with the fields you want to keep, and then Append into the new one?

Comment: What is `input_data` set to when that line of code is run?

Comment: @Vince That is a workaround. However, it surprises me that following the example in the documentation results in an error.

Comment: @PolyGeo None, I just use the same feature, thereby expecting a different dataset (i.e. less columns) after running the line of code.

Comment: You are using a version of ArcGIS Pro that does not implement the third parameter where you added "KEEP_FIELDS". Find your version number and look at the docs. Or open Pro and look at the tool in the tool and click the info icon (its a ? in a blue circle) to open the docs for that version of Pro. So you can either update Pro to a version that uses the updated DeleteField tool. Or you can write code to iterate through all fields and delete if there is a non-match for the ones you want to keep and the field is nonrequired (you can probably get that through field description)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code for the versions of ArcGIS Pro that does not implement the third optional parameter (as per the comment posted in the original question)

```
import arcpy

## path to the feature class to delete fields from
in_data = "path/to/feature_class"

## name of fields you wish to keep
keep_fields = ["fld1_name", "fld2_name"]

## for each field in the dataset
for fld in arcpy.ListFields(in_data):
    ## if it is not in keep_filds list and in nonrequired
    if fld.name not in keep_fields and not fld.required:
        ## the delete the field
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_data, fld.name)
```